# What's the difference between these two GPO options?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy, security

What's the difference between the two GPO options below?

1. `NETWORK ACCESS : DO NOT ALLOW storage of credentials or .NET passports for network`
2. `NETWORK ACCESS : DO NOT ALLOW storage of passwords and credentials for network authentications`

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say that they are essentially the same, but #1 is the verbage used for Server 2003, and #2 is Server 2008 and above.

Sources:

1 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779377(v=ws.10).aspx

2 - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349805(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_39

Look at what versions of Windows are listed in the "applies to" at the beginning of each article.